# Updated Django Application on aws ec2 and failed working

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

My aws ec2 substance with aws rds was working perfectly fine. Then I have made some changes to my django application by installing pymysql to make sure MySQLclient work and updates a upload function for my admin portal. I have checked everything using the local server, everything works fine. But when I git pull it through ssh ubuntu kernal. I could not access to my aws ec2 anymore, it says ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. What could be the potential problem?

I tried accessing through local server and it works fine